# Multiple voltage diode protection

Tags: power-supply, low-power

I'm attempting to build a circuit that can be powered from either a external power connection (+12V in the diagram), or via USB (VBUS). I realized that I also want to be able to connect the USB for data purposes while +12V is connected (it's also used to power another part of the circuit), but don't want to backfeed power from VBUS into the regulator, or vice-versa.

I've added diodes D1 & D2, is this enough? And what kind of diode is best suited for this?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: (There are dual MOSFET+ combos for this purpose.)